# Does Eigenface method use unsupervised trainning

Tags: python, face-recognition

Eigenface method is a powerful method in face recognition. It uses the training images to find the eigenfaces and then use these eigenfaces to represent a new test image. Do the images in training dataset need to be labeled, or it is unsupervised training?

Answer (score 0):

Eigenfaces require supervised learning.  You generally supply several of each subject, classifying them by identifying the subject.  The eigenface model then classifies later images (often real-time snapshots) as to identity.